# Shopware 6 adds HSTS header also including subdomains

Tags: shopware6, hsts

We run a Shopware 6 Shop on https://example.com but there is also a CNAME newsletter.example.com for Cleverreach links which does not use https. This links break because Shopware sends a HSTS header for all subdomains.

https://github.com/shopware/platform/blame/a7bb639b0c00722036449ba335ade178eb40c5ba/src/Core/Framework/Routing/CoreSubscriber.php#L50

```
$response->headers->set('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains');
```

What's the best way to disable this ? I think removing `includeSubDomains` should be enough. Does this have security implications for the shop if we make the newsletter subdomain work?

Additionally we would try getting https://newsletter.example.com working - but what is the reason Shopware also feels responsible for the subdomains?

EDIT:

Current workaround in Apache config with mod_header:

```
Header edit Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains" "max-age=31536000"
```

Still the question stands, why Shopware is doing this and if this workaround has negative security implicaitons.

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is there for a reason; disabling it, even on subdomains, is a security risk. Basically it means that the content of the subdomain can be modified by a man-in-the-middle. That is a problem. E.g. If people click on any links on the page, as it might trick the user into visiting a fake login page.